# Unable to import plot_lines from utils on vscode mac

Tags: python, import

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from utils import plot_lines
```

getting a message saying import plot_lines

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_lines' from 'utils'
```

Running a virtual environment. Have pip installed numpy, matplotlib.pyplot and utils already

Comment: Well, there's no `plot_lines` in `utils` package. What are you actually trying to import? Do you have a `PyPI` link or any other reference?